# Node Red. Spilt/Break message from mqtt broker(mosca)

Tags: mqtt, node-red

How do I break/split the message received from mqtt broker(mosca)? The whole message come with packet, topic, messageid, payload, etc. I just need the payload {"T":"t"} displayed at the debug node. I tried the split and switch node, it doesn't seem to work, no response at the output.

mqtt device
[image]

mqtt broker
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using the MQTT-in node to subscribe to the topics you want rather than the output of the Mosca broker node, which will include EVERY message sent to the broker (with all the internal detail that you don't want.

But you can move the `msg.packet.payload` to `msg.payload` with the change node. Then run that output through the JSON node which will parse the String representation of the JSON object back into a proper object.

(If you use the MQTT-in node you will still need to use the JSON node)

Comment: I have several devices which I needed them to send whatever updates to a broker through a network. So I believe I need a broker as the middleman in order it to work.

Comment: yes, you need a broker, but you shouldn't be using the output from the broker node to consume the messages. You should be using the MQTT-in node to subscribe to the topics the devices publish on. The mosca node is meant for quick prototyping, in a real system you should be using a proper broker external to Node-RED

Comment: Very thank you hardillb, that made me understand about mqtt better. Now everything works as expected :)